# Error 2048 with a PHP Form

Tags: php

I am getting this error when hosting my PHP form. The server I am using is PHP 5.x.

I found a post about removing  " error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT " from the php file but this did not work.

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

EDIT: code as per OP's comment

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_WARNING);
$variables = array( "subject" => $_POST["subject"],
                    "message" => $_POST["senderComment"],
                    "name"    => $_POST["senderName"],
                    "email"   => $_POST["senderEmail"], );
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message and the line of code the error occurs in.

Comment: The very **last** thing you want to do is suppress the message.

Comment: It just says Error #2048 - The site is www.mt.com/ecatalog

Comment: Use the tell a friend button on the button right

Comment: Is there a way to attach the text files?

Comment: @Bill edit the code into your question and use the `{}` button on the code so it gets indented properly - but please only the relevant parts, not the full code

Comment: {<?php

error_reporting(E_WARNING);

$variables = array(
 "subject"  => $_POST["subject"],
 "message"  => $_POST["senderComment"],
 "name"   => $_POST["senderName"],
 "email"   => $_POST["senderEmail"],
);}

Comment: That is only part of it as requested

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on to the right track

http://phpgun.com/what-is-php-error-no-2048/

Also refer php.net/manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Basically,Starting from PHP 5 if you are using error reporting E | STRICT it will warn you on using deprecated functions or methodology this is to ensure your code implementation is the latest standard from PHP.

If this error 2048 occuring in your application and buy any chance it is a legacy code from someone else. You can just remove the E | STRICT the value in the php.ini as bellow.
view source
print?
1.error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT

This will remove all the notice..

Comment: Here is the first part of the code and it is still not working... Thanks so much for the help

Comment: {<?php

error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT;

$variables = array(
 "message"  => $_POST["senderComment"],
 "sendername"   => $_POST["senderName"],
 "senderemail"   => $_POST["senderEmail"],
 "friendname"   => $_POST["recipientName"],
 "friendemail"   => $_POST["recipientEmail"],
);}

Comment: Also I searched for php.ini in the file folder and found it but the only info inside it is {upload_max_filesize=200M
post_max_size=200M
memory_limit=128M}